# PHP4 constructor naming convention in PHP5

Tags: php, oop

Aside from the "you won't have to change the name", is there any real problems with retaining the PHP4 style constructor names:

```
ClassName($args)
```

in PHP5?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because named constructors were only retained in PHP5 for backwards compatibility with PHP4, they are more likely to become deprecated in a later release of PHP than `__construct()` is, so that's something to keep in mind if you're writing something that you intend to have longevity.

Comment: One of the goals with PHP 5 was added consistency. PHP is moving towards having code that is automatically invoked by the engine prefixed with __. We see this with new class options __construct, destruct, call, get, set, sleep, etc. We also see with __autoload. 

Using parent::__construct() also works when you use the PHP 4 style constructor, which can be a bit confusing.

Answer (score 6):

If you use the old style constructor names, you're creating a bit of confusion around situations like this

```
class A
{
    public function A()
    {
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function B()
    {
        //how do/should I call the parent constructor?
        //parent::A(); ?
        //parent::__construct(); ?
    }
}
```

If someone sees the old style constructor and switches it to a less-old style constructor, you risk functionality breaking.  Also, if you have to juggle your object heirarchy so that B extends a different class, you need to manually change all the calls to `parent::A()`, or someone not familiar with the "constructor is a method with the class name" construct (meaning anyone who learned PHP in the last 5 years) may not know to do that and subtle breaking will occur.

Answer (score 3):

For PHP5, there's no problem with retaining it.  However, if the class has a __construct() function, it will be called instead.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), that's the only drawback.

Answer (score 0):

No. Besides that it's ugly-ish (imo) and takes away one possible function name. ^^

Answer (score 0):

in php 4 oop is more a hack than everything else here is a code snipped for a constructor in php 5 style but its compatible for php 4

```
class Object
{
    function Object()
    {
        $args= func_get_args();
        call_user_func_array
        (
            array(&$this, '__construct'),
            $args
        );
    }

    function __construct()
    {
        // Abstrakt Funktion
    }
}
```